# WPF C# Button background not changing on MouseEnter Event

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background, mouseevent

I have created a `Button` object in WPF and hooked a `MouseEnter` event for it , such as on `MouseEnter` event for `Button`, the `Background` changes:

```
Button button = new Button();  
button.Background = Brushes.Red;  
button.BorderBrush=Brushes.Red;  
button.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(button_MouseEnter);`
```

and my event is :

```
private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    button.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    button.BorderBrush = Brushes.Yellow;
}
```

I got my button `BorderBrush` changed on `MouseEnter` event, but `Button` background is not working, instead its `Background` is changing to a default gray color on `MouseEnter` event.

So where am i going wrong , can somebody help me .

Comment: I assume that the styles of the buttons are stronger then your event binding . I've not tested it but perhaps you would need to restlye the button

Comment: [Dependency Precedence][1]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Here's the thing:

    <Button Background="Yellow">
    </Buttton>

Now you can't change you background using triggers, style. Read the link, hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The default wpf style template contains a trigger handling the mouse-over effect, I´d guess that this is interfeering with your handler. Try setting a style without triggers to your button (btw. this is the wpf way you should use, styling your control using a template and not code behind) and see if your code is working.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies , I have followed your steps and resources , my aim is that have to achieve this only in code behind , so I  have changed my Event a little bit , it works but the background changes just a fraction second , Is this correct what i did?

```
 private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
       Button button = sender as Button;
       Style style = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(Button));
       style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow));
       button.Style = style;
       button.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
   }
```